# A function to count how many different characters are in a string

Tags: c, char

I've found this function on the internet and I find it to be very useful 
but I am new to programming, and could someone please explain briefly what does it exactly do

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  int diffcount(char* s)
    {
        unsigned char seen[127];
        int cnt=0,i;
        for(i=0;i<127;i++)
            seen[i]=0;
        for(i=0;s[i];i++)
        {
            if(!seen[(int)s[i]])
            {
                cnt++;
                seen[(int)s[i]]=1;
            }
        }return cnt;
    }

int main(void) {
    char string[20];
    scanf("%s",string);
    printf("Razlicitih znakova: %d\n", diffcount(string));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Briefly: this function counts *how many different characters are in a string*

Comment: what is `diffcount()` supposed to do? I will not read the function, first give a description of what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we init an empty array of zeros int `seen[127];` 
"*seen*" array is used to find out whether char with code i has been met in the array `s` : `if seen[i]==1` than `(char)i` was in the string `s`.

After that we make a loop through `char* s` and check if char `s[i]` has already been met by looking at the value of  `seen[s[i]];` and if it is false we put `seen[s[i]]=true` (because we met it) and increase our counter. 
The result of the function is the value of variable cnt

This may also help: 
each char has it's code between zero and 127. For example, `(int)'a' = 97`.
bool in the C is just the same as `int`, that's why we sometimes use 0 and 1 instead of true and false

Comment: "each char has it's code between zero and 127" is questionable.  `char` values commonly seen are in the ASCII range of 0 to 127, but `char` has at least 256 different values.

Comment: @chux yes,you 're right of course. I didn't mention it for simplicity,should I edit the answer?

Comment: IMO, OP does not realize it and would benefit with more clarity.  Given the potential `char` is signed and the range of `char` could be quite large, simply checking for 0 to 126 (or 127) maybe sufficient.